# Picture upload form using php

Tags: php, image, forms, upload

Could somebody please tell me why my php code is not working, as far as I know (im teaching myself) the file is being uploaded to temp folder, then it is being checked for size format etc, then it is being saved into my upload file on the server.

However it is not working. Could somebody help me

```
<?php
if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0)
{
echo "Error: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br>";
}
else
 {
  echo "Upload: " . $_FILES["file"]["name"] . "<br>";
  echo "Type: " . $_FILES["file"]["type"] . "<br>";
  echo "Size: " . ($_FILES["file"]["size"] / 1024) . " kB<br>";
  echo "Stored in: " . $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"];
  }




$allowedExts = array("gif", "jpeg", "jpg", "png");
$temp = explode(".", $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
$extension = end($temp);
if ((($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/gif")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpeg")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpg")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/pjpeg")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/x-png")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/png"))
&& ($_FILES["file"]["size"] < 20000)
&& in_array($extension, $allowedExts))
{
if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0)
{
echo "Error: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br>";
}
else
{
echo "Upload: " . $_FILES["file"]["name"] . "<br>";
echo "Type: " . $_FILES["file"]["type"] . "<br>";
echo "Size: " . ($_FILES["file"]["size"] / 1024) . " kB<br>";
echo "Stored in: " . $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"];
}
}
else
{
echo "Invalid file";
}



$allowedExts = array("gif", "jpeg", "jpg", "png");
$temp = explode(".", $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
$extension = end($temp);
if ((($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/gif")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpeg")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpg")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/pjpeg")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/x-png")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/png"))
&& ($_FILES["file"]["size"] < 20000)
&& in_array($extension, $allowedExts))
{
if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0)
{
echo "Return Code: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br>";
}
else
{
echo "Upload: " . $_FILES["file"]["name"] . "<br>";
echo "Type: " . $_FILES["file"]["type"] . "<br>";
echo "Size: " . ($_FILES["file"]["size"] / 1024) . " kB<br>";
echo "Temp file: " . $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"] . "<br>";

if (file_exists("upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]))
  {
  echo $_FILES["file"]["name"] . " already exists. ";
  }
else
  {
  move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],
  "upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
  echo "Stored in: " . "upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"];
  }
 }
}
else
{
echo "Invalid file";
}

?>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, if somebody could just please have a look through it and tell me what needs to be changed. Thanks in advance

```
<form action="upload_file.php" method="post"
enctype="multipart/form-data">
<label for="file">Filename:</label>
<input type="file" name="file" id="file"><br>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Comment: "However it is not working" Don't just say that it's not working. Say what _is_ happening. Are you getting any errors? If so, what are they? Is the image being saved to an unexpected location? Try to give more information.

Comment: make sure you upload folder on server has proper permission to write ..

Answer (score 1):

As I can't see your HTML file, I'm guessing but you've probably not set the `enctype` on your form tag:

```
<form action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
...
</form>
```

Comment: Yeah but how did I know that? Please upload your HTML form so we can see :)